# React - Passing data to this.props.children not working

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a parent component where I am using an `EnhancedTable` component as one of the child components. The `EnhancedTable` gets children as prop. You can see it in the example below:

```
<EnhancedTable headerRows={headerRows} data={eksamenssettene}>        
  {({eksamensett, handleClick, isSelected}) => (
      <TableRow
        hover
        onClick={() => handleClick(eksamensett.id)}
        role="checkbox"
        aria-checked={isSelected}
        tabIndex={-1}
        key={eksamensett.id}
        selected={isSelected}
      >
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
          {eksamensett.klasse.klassekode}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{eksamensett.navn}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{eksamensset.fastRekkefolge ? 'Fast eksamensset' : 'Randomisert'}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{formatStringToLocalDate(eksamensset.opprettetDatoTid)}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{getElapsedTime(eksamensset.endretDatoTid)}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    )}
  </EnhancedTable>
```

In EnhancedTable, I am using this children to pass it those props that it is expecting. In my case `eksamensett, handleClick, isSelected`. I am doing that like this, below is the part of the component where I am doing that:

```
    <TableBody>
      {stableSort(data, getSorting(order, orderBy))
        .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
        .map(n => {
          const isSelected = this.isSelected(n.id);
          return React.cloneElement(children, { eksamensett: n, isSelected,  handleClick: (id) => this.handleClick(id)});

        })}
      {emptyRows > 0 && (
        <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
          <TableCell colSpan={6} />
        </TableRow>
      )}
    </TableBody>
```

But, I am getting an undefined for eksamensett:

> Line 104:  'eksamensset' is not defined  no-undef   Line 105: 
>   'eksamensset' is not defined  no-undef   Line 106:  'eksamensset' is
>   not defined  no-undef

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `eksamensset` vs `eksamensett` double `ss` vs `tt`

Comment: Oh, thanks for spotting that :) that it was something more serious :D